# Seeking with Streaming API

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to create an aggregator that pulls song links to a central site from many different blogs using youtube, soundcloud, etc. I was wondering where I can find more info about the js streaming api. I'd like to be able to seek with the js streaming api, along with have a callback be called when that song is done playing.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you'll want to check out:

1. Our [HTML5 Widget](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) has an API that allows you to bind code to events and control the player widget (e.g. seek to a specific point in a track). This'll work if you want to use our player widget anyway.
2. The [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) uses [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/) under the hood. Certain methods, such as `SC.stream` will return a `soundObject` which you can use to seek and bind code to events.

Hope that helps. Comment if you have any questions and I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really help me. I can't find a single example of stopping a stream anywhere. In fact I can't seem to bind to any of the methods described in sound manager. Neither of these work.

+++

```
SC.initialize({
client_id: "xxx"
});

// Stream the audio
sound = SC.stream("/tracks/293");
sound.play();
```

+++

```
SC.stream("/tracks/293", {
  autoPlay: true,
     ontimedcomments: function(comments){                  console.log(comments[0].body);
  },
  onplay: function(sound){
      alert(sound);
  }
});
```

+++

Really, I just want to create a custom streaming player where I can change the music, and stop and hit play (not in jQuery). I haven't found much on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

use SC object to stop the playback. more information at
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#methods

```
SC.recordStop();
```

top play the song again 
'SC.recordPlay();'

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Jesse, Use this to play songs.

```
SC.get('/tracks/294', function(track){
  console.log(track)
  // SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, document.getElementById('player'))
})
```

Make sure you have a div#player in your html somewhere. Then, if you uncomment that line you'll see SoundCloud's branded music player.